# localhost nao abre no navegador com XAMPP

Tags: xampp, localhost

Recentemente instalei o XAMPP e funcionava perfeitamente, starta e tudo mais.

Depois de um tempo eu abria *localhost* e não aparecia nada, dava

> esta página da web não pode ser exibida

Já tentei 127.0.0.1 e já troquei a porta para 8080, mas o erro continua o mesmo.

O proxy da internet esta desativado e o *firewall* do Windows normal, utilizo Windows 7.

Saída do painel do XAMPP:

```
17:52:03 [main] All prerequisites found 
17:52:03 [main] Initializing Modules 
17:52:03 [main] Starting Check-Timer 
17:52:03 [main] Control Panel Ready 
17:52:08 [Apache] Attempting to start Apache app... 
17:52:11 [Apache] Status change detected: running 
17:52:13 [mysql] Attempting to start MySQL app... 
17:52:15 [mysql] Status change detected: running
```

O que me mostra:

```
Esta página não pode ser exibida

•Verifique se o endereço da Web http://localhost:8080  está correto.
•Procure a página com seu mecanismo de pesquisa.
•Atualize a página em poucos minutos.
```

Comment: @juancarlos Tem como postar o arquivo de configuração do Apache?

Comment: Não precisa postar o arquivo inteiro, apenas procure por `DocumentRoot` e copie a linha inteira na sua pergunta

Comment: DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"